# Apache and PHP separation of vhosts

Tags: php, apache, vhosts

Hello i want to ask how to setup apache in way that I will get on each vhost documentroot = "/" and separate php.ini.

i have this kind of folder structure:

```
root/
 domain1/
   php.files ect
 domain2/
   php.files ect
```

i want to get in each php file in domain1 & domain2 $_SERVER['DOCUMENTROOT'] = "/" and have ability to set individual php.ini which will override main php.ini directives.

I tried many things to set this documentroot but still have no idea how to make it work. I tried also with suPhp in order to handle php.ini but it seems to not meet my needs, or I dont know how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit 2 files
1-  file is vhosts :

Domain : example 
domain files : C:\xampp\htdocs\example

```
<VirtualHost example>
    ServerAdmin ssc@ssc.com
    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\example
    ServerName example
    ErrorLog logs/ssc-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/ssc-host.example.com-access_log common

</VirtualHost>
```

2- Also if you using windows you need to edit hosts file :

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Add this line

127.0.0.1   example

3- Restart your Apache server

4- write example in your browser

and now you have your domain .

Comment: I have dedicated server with domain pointing to my apache and i have something like this:


    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "../../../www/domain.com"
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
     <Directory "../../../www/domain.com">
      Options +Indexes
      AllowOverride all
      Order deny,allow
      allow from all
     </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>


I want to get sth like:

    DocumentRoot /
    Alias "/" "../../../www/domain.com"

Comment: Sorry , I didn't understood you . Explain please .